# How does systemUpdate WINDOWED parameter work for apk updates?

Tags: android, android-management-api

I tried to use the systemUpdate parameter with type WINDOWED and startMinutes/endMinutes like that :

```
"systemUpdate": {
    "endMinutes": 700,
    "startMinutes": 645,
    "type": "WINDOWED"
  }
```

However it doesn't seem to do anything about app updates. The documentation about WINDOWED option says :

> Install automatically within a daily maintenance window. This also configures Play apps to be updated within the window. This is strongly recommended for kiosk devices because this is the only way apps persistently pinned to the foreground can be updated by Play.

which is my case. I have a kiosk app and an other app that I install from private Play Store but whatever settings I use in systemUpdate they're automatically updated as soon as the policy is applied, even during the time window I defined. I would like to use this feature cause I don't want my devices to be updated while they're being used but I don't know how.

Did someone encounter this issue? Or maybe someone can guide me to use it correctly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's weird that apps gets updated immediately when updating the policy. Did you set a `minimumVersionCode` for the apps in the policy?

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks for your answer! And no I did not use a `minimumVersionCode` on my kiosk app at that moment (I actually added it yesterday but without the windowed parameter). 

However I have the `"appAutoUpdatePolicy": "NEVER"` parameter on my policy to avoid auto-updates.

What parameters would you advice so I can make new tests?